# Notification Firebase PendingIntent return null value - AndroidX

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, android-pendingintent

I already searched all sourced from the internet how to return a value from pending intent when the user clicks the notification, it does launch MainActivity but IntentExtra was null, this is my code

```
public class FirebaseNotificationManager extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "Firebase_MSG";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getFrom(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void sendNotification(String messageTitle, String messageBody) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("NotificationJumpPKG", "SignUp");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(FirebaseNotificationManager.this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.primary_applogo)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);


    NotificationManagerCompat mNoticationMgr = NotificationManagerCompat.from(FirebaseNotificationManager.this);
    mNoticationMgr.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

//MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String mNotificationJump = intent.getStringExtra("NotificationJumpPKG");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dapat" + mNotificationJump, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (mNotificationJump != null) {
        if (mNotificationJump.equals("SignUp")) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignupFormActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        } else if (mNotificationJump.equals(("SearchFinal"))) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchFinalActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In FirebaseNotificationManager class you are creating intent for ResultActivity class, while you are checking flags in MainActivity class

Comment: @ked that was my second attemption, when I defined it into MainActivity.class, it doesn't work, when I try to use another Activity (ResultActivity.class) it doesn't work too